# Site blocking using Privoxy is not working

Tags: windows-10, proxy, internet-connection

So I was trying to block a specific webpage like "reddit.com/r/{webpage-name}" through Privoxy, I set up Privoxy with the help of an answer from [Joshua Robinson](https://superuser.com/users/122322/joshua-robison)

[Block specific URL on web browsers](https://superuser.com/questions/393967/block-specific-url-on-web-browsers)

I followed every step and then at last I restarted Privoxy. But when I went to the targeted webpage it still got loaded and did not get blocked.

How can I block it , what is going wrong?

Currently my file blacklist.action looks like this:

```
{ +block }
www.reddit.com/r/{sub_reddit_name}
```

and the websites that I wanted to whitelist are in whitelist.action

```
{ -block }
www.google.com
```

also I have referenced both of these files in config.txt file so that their respective action can be triggered.

```
actionsfile blacklist.action   
actionsfile whitelist.action
```

I have set enforce-blocks to 1

Now when I start Privoxy it is supposed to block "www.reddit.com/r/{subreddit_name}", but when I go to this subreddit it still gets loaded.

Note - I don't have cygwin installed as I don't know it would help in this case.

Operating System - Windows 10

Contents of C:\Program Files (x86)\Privoxy:

```
doc {folder}
templates {folder}
blacklist.action
whitelist.action
config.txt
default.action
default.filter
license.txt
match-all.action
mgwz.dll
privoxy.exe
privoxy.log
privoxy_uninstall.exe
README.txt
trust.txt
user.action
user.filter
whitelist.action
```

Also I've checked if privoxy is enabled or not, and it running perfectly, just failing to block the targeted webpage.

Update - I think it has to do something with "https" connection as the answer to this question suggests. But I couldn't wrap my head around it.

[How to block specific domains and urls using privoxy](https://superuser.com/questions/1003929/how-to-block-specific-domains-and-urls-using-privoxy?rq=1)

Privoxy version - 3.0.21 (not the latest version)

**But I want to enable the blockage of this webpage on every browser and not just firefox as the answer to the above question suggests.**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What are your operating system and browser? Add the contents of your `/etc/privoxy/` files to your post.

Comment: can i add a screenshot of the contents of do i have to write them in a code block

Comment: thanks , I've added the details now  @harrymc